# Sqlite design for cross linked tables and foreign keys usage

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I don't know if this is the right place to ask. Because it is a question regarding sql database design I was thinking about database administrator but because the target of that site is database professionals (and I'm absolutely not a professional) I'll just post my question here. Please point me to the right place if you think there's a better place for this type of question.

**Getting to the question.**

I'm designing a database for translations of literary works. Because this involves people and people often don't fit in a "static" data model I have a pretty convoluted schema. Here is just a section of it, regarding people's names. Because foreign authors are involved (expecially Japanese) I have the added problem of transliteration for people names. At present the structure of the database for people and names is as follows

[image: db_schema]

Let's take an example:

I have a person called "Kyokutei Bakin", which transliterates as 曲亭馬琴 in ideograms and キョクテイ バキン in japanese phonetic alphabet. This author is also known as "Takizawa Bakin" (滝沢馬琴, タキザワ バキン） and so on...

The 3 table structure with one to many relationships account for a person having multiple names (biographical_name, pen_name, ecc...) and for the fact that every name can have multiple phonetic readings.

This is all good. When I search for someone I just LEFT JOIN the tables and add OR conditions for the various fields. eg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name.name_text, phonetic_name.name_text FROM name
LEFT JOIN phonetic_name ON (name.name_id=phonetic_name.name_id)
WHERE (name.name_text LIKE "%bak%")
OR (phonetic_name.name_text LIKE "%馬琴%");
```

My problem is that I want one of the names to be the main name of that person. The way I've done it is adding a "main_name" column in the "person" table that points to the "name_id" column of the "name" table. So that I can `JOIN name ON (person.main_name=name.name_id)` when I want just the main name.

**My doubt is:**

-Is it a good practice to cross-link two tables?

(Here "name" references "person" on person_id, but at the same "person" references "name" for main_name).

-Can this cause problems?

-How do I set foreign keys in this kind of situation?

-In case this is way too messy, how can I improve the design?

**Additional info:**
Being a design problem the sql implementation should not be so important, but just in case it does, I'm using sqlite3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally simplify the design like this:

Table: `person`

- `person_id` (primary key)
- `...`

Table: `name`

- `name_id` (primary key)
- `name`
- `name_type`
- `parent_name_id` (foreign key of itself)
- `person_id` (foreign key of person table)

The table `name` has a recursive relationship where `parent_name_id` contains the `name_id` of the main name of the person. Note that for the main name `name_id=parent_name_id`. In the column `name_type` you can store the type of name (phonetic, ideogram, kanji, etc.). You can possibly normalize further the `name_type` into a dedicated table if you wish to have pure third normal form.

I would say the main benefit of this design is that it greatly simplifies your query when querying for names of any type. You can simply run something like this:

```
Select distinct b.person_id, b.name as main_name
From name a
Inner join name b on a.parent_name_id=b.name_id
Where a.name like ‘%...%’
```

In addition you can store as many names as you want for a single person.

If you want to return several names from different types you can do like this:

```
Select distinct b.person_id,
b.name as main_name,
c.name as kanji_name,
d.name as katakana_name
From name a
Inner join name b on a.parent_name_id=b.name_id
Left join name c on b.parent_name_id=c.parent_name_id and c.name_type=‘kanji’
Left join name d on b.parent_name_id=d.parent_name_id and d.name_type=‘katakana’
Etc...
Where a.name like ‘%...%’
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The inner reference to the main name is an interesting solution. I suppose with most alternatives one has to take into account the tradeoffs. For example, because in addition to the alphabet I also have the "category of the name" (eg: proper name, pen name, ecc..) these will end to be duplicate entries for every phonetic alternative. But probably in this case is not a big deal.

Comment: Also with the multiple tables I have now, joining on main_name, I can obtain a single row result for one person (which is useful to me to return data on search without post processing it, say, in php). But I cannot see a way to do it with the structure you proposed. I'm quite sure it can be done, just I can't figure out how.

Comment: @HirabayashiTaro you can just do a select distinct of person_id and main_name to have one single record. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @HirabayashiTaro regarding the category of name, can one name belong to several categories? If yes it means you ha a many to many relationship between name and category. I would suggest you store this info into a dedicated junction table. Ex: name_category(named_id, category_id) and then you have a dedicated table category(category_id, category_name...)

Comment: As far as I can think of, one name should belong to a single category, so a one to many relationship will suffice. With regard to returning one row for every individual person (I'm thinking of the return row as "person_id, name_latin, name_in_kanji, name_in_katakana") I was searching about it here on stack, and I think that concatenation of the various names with GROUP_CONCAT should do the trick. But I'm not that familar with sql so I'll need some time to learn about it.

Comment: @HirabayashiTaro there was a mistake in my first query in the join, I have corrected it and added a second query to fetch the different names in the result set